# Deleting selected Features from select by location

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

If I'd like to delete features from select by location process , what should I do?  Because features 's selected already.

```
Layer0000 = iface.activeLayer()

Kanjanaburi_Select =  processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {'INPUT':'C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/เดสก์ท็อป/TEST/Kanjanaburi Pacel_REFAC.gpkg|layername=Kanjanaburi Pacel_REFAC','PREDICATE':[1],'INTERSECT':'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\OneDrive\\เดสก์ท็อป\\TEST\\Kanjanaburi Pacel6605_REFAC.gpkg|layername=Kanjanaburi Pacel6605_REFAC','METHOD':0})

if Layer0000.selectedFeatureCount() > 0:

    Layer0000.startEditing()

    Layer0000.deleteSelectedFeatures()

    Layer0000.commitChanges()
```

Comment: How does your code not work?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

Use the algorithm `saga:deleteselectionfromfeatureslayer` if your code does not work.

Also you could use `saga:selectanddelete` to do it all in one step.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm a really beginner learning PyQgis by myself. That's why it's so difficult. But for this problem I found out a solution already by tring writting codes getting in this web. Hoolay.